# React Native custom component reuse with dynamic function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-component

I have a popup component which has a button and that button has a callback function attached to it. Now I am using this component in two different screen and passing the callback function dynamically while rendering the component. But now the problem is it only renders the first components function and ignores the second components function

I have tried renaming the  import statement but no difference

Component.js

```
class actions extends Component {
render() {
  return (
       <Modal>
          <Button block  onPress={()=>{this.props.someAction()}}>
             <Text>Action Button</Text>
           </Button>
        </Modal>
        )
}
```

Page1.js

```
import Component from "Component.js"

emailOne(){
   alert("Component 1 Email");
}

<Component someAction={this.emailOne}>
```

Page2.js

```
import Component from "Component.js"

emailTwo(){
   alert("Component 2 Email");
}

<Component someAction={this.emailTwo}>
```

Here when I click on the page one component button it alerts "Component 1 Email" but page 2 just throws an error the function emailTwo is undefined.

I am using react navigation bottom tab navigator to navigate between pages. 
I have no idea why this is happening and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
 class actions extends Component {
      render() {
         const {actionOne, actionTwo, actionThree} = this.props
          return (
           <Modal>
            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={actionOne}>
               <Text>Action Button one</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
             <TouchableOpacity  onPress={actionTwo}>
               <Text>Action Button two</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity  onPress={actionThree}>
               <Text>Action Button three</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
           </Modal>
       )
   }

   Page1.js

 import Component from "Component.js"

     emailOne= () =>{
         alert("Component 1 Email");
         }
     emailTwo= () =>{
         alert("Component 1 Email");
         }
    emailThree= () =>{
         alert("Component 1 Email");
         }

   <Component actionOne={()=>{this.emailOne()}}
              actionTwo={()=>{this.emailTwo()}} 
              actionThree={()=>{this.emailThree()}}>


      Page2.js

       import Component from "Component.js"

            emailFour = () =>{
              alert("Component 2 Email");
             }
            emailFive = () =>{
              alert("Component 2 Email");
             }
         emailSix = () =>{
              alert("Component 2 Email");
             }

         <Component actionOne={()=>{this.emailFour()}}
              actionTwo={()=>{this.emailFive()}} 
              actionThree={()=>{this.emailSix()}}>
```

Snack example is https://snack.expo.io/r1Ch1azEV

Comment: tried this, It only alerts "Component 1 Email" from both  the pages.

Comment: It has to work, check with the new edit i have snack example as well for me its working fine

Comment: I am using  bottom tab navigator is it because of that ?